# How to execute a shell program taking inputs with python?

Tags: python-3.x, shell, command-line-interface, os.system, cubesat-protocol

First of all, I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and Python 3.8.
I would like to run a program that takes command line inputs. I managed to start the program from python with the os.system() command, but after starting the program it is impossible to send the inputs. The program in question is a product interface application that uses the CubeSat Space Protocol (CSP) as a language. However, the inputs used are encoded in a .c file with their corresponding .h header.

In the shell, it looks like this:
[starting the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBHYm.png)

In python, it looks like this:

```
import os
os.chdir('/home/augustin/workspaceGS/gs-sw-nanosoft-product-interface-application-2.5.1')
os.system('./waf')
os.system('./build/csp-client -k/dev/ttyUSB1')
os.system('cmp ident') #cmp ident is typically the kind of command that does not work on python
```

The output is the same as in the shell but without the "cmp ident output", that is to say it's impossible for me to use the csp-client#

As you can probably see, I'm a real beginner trying to be as clear and precise as possible. I can of course try to give more information if needed. Thanks for your help !

Comment: I know nothing about CSP, by the way... do you mean you want to write a Python script that sends a few CSP commands that you already know ahead of time? Or do you mean you want to write a Python script that asks you for input, reads what you type and passes it to CSP and shows you the result? What is `waf`? What is the command you sent? Is something attached to a USB port? What?

Comment: In order to see how your program works, can you try running it non-interactively? So, if the command you want send is `cmp ident` can you run `echo "cmp ident" | csp-client -k/dev/ttyUSB1` and see if that works adequately?

Comment: I gave you too little information it's my fault : I'm using a nanosatellite imager that uses CSP as protocol, and this imager is controlled thanks to command lines (for example, the command "nanocam snap" will snap a picture). Of course, these commands are encoded in a C file with its corresponding header. So, a RS232-to-USB converter is plugged in the USB1 port. Waf is a Python based build system (https://waf.io/book/). Regarding Python, the final code aims at pressing a button in a GUI that would take a picture, without using command lines, but for now I just cannot access to the cap-client#

Comment: I just tried to run what you told me to, it does not work with this exact command, BUT it works with `echo "cmp ident" | ./csp-client -k/dev/ttyUSB1` however I don't really see how could it help me but I'm gonna think about it

Comment: What command do you type to exit `csp-client` please?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do, but I would probably recommend that you compile CSP with the python bindings enabled. (using `--enable-python3-bindings` in the WAF command). With this enabled, you can build your application entirely in Python. Here is an example CSP CLI that I made for a Cubesat project: https://github.com/AlbertaSat/ex2_ground_station_software/blob/master/src/CSPHandler.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try and give you some hints to get you started - though bear in mind I do not know any of your tools, i.e. `waf` or `csp-client`, but hopefully that will not matter.

I'll number my points so you can refer to the steps easily.

---

**Point 1**

If `waf` is a build system, I wouldn't keep running that every time you want to run your `csp-client`. Just use `waf` to rebuild when you have changed your code - that should save time.

---

**Point 2**

When you change directory to `/home/augustin/workspaceGS/gs-sw-nanosoft-product-interface-application-2.5.1` and then run `./build/csp-client` you are effectively running:

```
/home/augustin/workspaceGS/gs-sw-nanosoft-product-interface-application-2.5.1/build/csp-client -k/dev/ttyUSB1
```

But that is rather annoying, so I would make a symbolic link to that that from `/usr/local/bin` so that you can run it just with:

```
csp-client -k/dev/ttyUSB1
```

So, I would make that symlink with:

```
ln -s /home/augustin/workspaceGS/gs-sw-nanosoft-product-interface-application-2.5.1/build/csp-client  /usr/local/bin/csp-client
```

You MAY need to put `sudo` at the start of that command. Once you have that, you should be able to just run:

```
csp-client -k/dev/ttyUSB1
```

---

**Point 3**

Your Python code doesn't work because every `os.system()` starts a completely new shell, unrelated to the previous line or shell. And the shell that it starts then exits before your next `os.system()` command.

As a result, the `cmp ident` command never goes to the `csp-client`. You really need to send the `cmp ident` command on the `stdin` or *"standard input"* of `csp-client`. You *can* do that in Python, it is described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html), but it's not all that easy for a beginner.

Instead of that, if you just have aa few limited commands you need to send, such as *"take a picture"*, I would make and test complete `bash` scripts in the Terminal, till I got them right and then just call those from Python. So, I would make a `bash` script in your HOME directory called, say `csp-snap` and put something like this in it:

```
#/bin/bash

# Extend PATH so we can find "/usr/local/bin/csp-client"
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin

{
   # Tell client to take picture
   echo "nanoncam snap" 
   # Exit csp-client
   echo exit
} | csp-client -k/dev/ttyUSB1
```

Now make that executable (only necessary once) with:

```
chmod +x $HOME/csp-snap
```

And then you can test it with:

```
$HOME/csp-snap
```

If that works, you can copy the script to `/usr/local/bin` with:

```
cp $HOME/csp-snap /usr/local/bin
```

You may need `sudo` at the start again.

Then you should be able to take photos from anywhere just with:

```
csp-snap
```

Then your Python code becomes easy:

```
os.system('/usr/local/bin/csp-snap')
```

Comment: I followed your instructions and it perfectly works ! Thank you so much

Comment: Brilliant - well done and good luck with your project. Come back and ask a new question if you get stuck - questions (and answers) are free :-)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the `pexpect` module might be what you're looking for rather than using `os.system` it's designed for controlling other applications and interacting with them like a human is using them. The documentation for it is available [here](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). But what you want will probably look something like this:

```py
import pexpect
p = pexpect.spawnu("/home/augustin/workspaceGS/gs-sw-nanosoft-product-interface-application-2.5.1/build/csp-client -k/dev/ttyUSB1")
p.expect("csp-client")
p.sendline("cmp indent")
print(p.read())
p.close()
```